# Sonarqube 6.2 finds only code duplication, no bugs, vulnerabilities or code smells

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm running Sonarqube 6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.01. When I was running Sonarqube 5.4 everything was working fine. After upgrading to 6.2, I scan my project directories, the analysis completes successfully, but the main dashboard page for each project says 0 Bugs, 0 Vulnerabilities, 0 Debt, 0 Code Smells, but it does find code duplication.

I don't see anything in the logs or config files that would allow the analysis to finish successfully but result in no issues found. I know for a fact there are a ton of issues with the code.

[image: screenshot of dashboard with "0" results]

Comment: Few sanity checks: language plugin still installed ? made sure that Quality Profile in use contains expected rules ? [Upgrade Guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) followed thoroughly ? For more details you could first provide logs of the analysis.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I downgraded to 5.6.4 and redid all my analyses and that's working normally. I didn't have more time to spend on getting it to work. If I restore that system I can rerun the analyses and share the logs.